# Linear Regression Seber, Exercise 1.b.2 - Why do the equalities hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

In Sebers *Linear Regression Analysis', the following problem is posed:
[image]

I eventually gave up and looked at the solution, in which the following is written:
[image]

I have two questions concerning this solution:

1. Where does he get the equation $\sum_i (\sigma _i ^2 + \mu_i ^2) - n*var[\overline X] + n*(E[X])^2$ from?
2. Why do the $\mu_i ^2$ and the $n(E[\overline X])^2$ disappear in the second equation?

The second question boggles me the most because as far as I understand it follows from the second equation that $n*\mu^2 + n(E[X])^2 = 0$ (right?) and I really don't see why that would be the case.

EDIT: Wording sounded weird (am not a native english speaker)

Answer (score 0):

$ E[\sum_i(X_i - \overline X)^2] =$
$E[\sum_i(X_i^2 - 2X_i{\overline X} + {\overline X}^2 )]$
=$\sum_i E[(X_i^2 - 2X_i{\overline X} + {\overline X}^2 )]$
$=\sum_i E[(X_i^2 - 2X_i{\overline X} + {\overline X}^2 )]$
$= \sum_i( E[(X_i^2] - E[2X_i{\overline X}] + E[{\overline X}^2 )])
$
$= \sum_i( \mu^2 + \sigma_i^2) - 2E[X_i{\overline X}] + (var[{\overline X}] +(E[{\overline X}])^2)
$
$= n \mu^2 + (\sum_i\sigma_i^2) - 2\sum_i E[X_i {\overline X}] + n \times var[{\overline X}] + n\mu^2$

Furthermore,
$\sum_i E[X_i {\overline X}] =
1/n\sum_i E[X_i (X_1 +...+X_i +...+X_n)]\\
=1/n\sum_i (n \mu^2 + \sigma_i^2) = n\mu^2 + 1/n\sum_i \sigma_i^2 \\
= n\mu^2 + n \times var(\overline X)
$

yielding finally 
$E[\sum_i(X_i - \overline X)^2] =
 (\sum_i\sigma_i^2) - n\times var(\overline X)$

Perhaps you should fill in some of the steps/gaps - I got tired of typing :)